# Correlation specifics in R

Tags: r, correlation

I have a small matrix with some NA's as follows:

```
test <- matrix(rnorm(25),5,5)
test[1,1] <- NA; test[2,1] <- NA; test[1,4] <- NA; test[3,4] <- NA
test
```

I want to calculate the correlation of each column with all others, i.e. the correlation matrix `cor(test)`. Moreover, I want to determine a minimum of non-NA pairs for the correlation to be calculated between two columns. Let's say in this example, the minimum of non-NA pairs for a correlation to be calculated is 4, so clearly columns 1 and 4 would be eliminated from the calculations and return NA for each of their correlations with any other columns. How can this be achieved?

My approach so far was to use:

```
cor(test,use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
```

In short: This is actually what I want: pairwise-complete observations; however, I also want to set a minimum for the complete (non-NA) pairs, which from my understanding is not possible in the basic function?

The solution has to work on also on datatables (dataframes).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 a <- !is.na(test)
 b <- cor(test,use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
 b[t(a)%*%a < 4] <- NA
```

Comment: thanks, this seems to do the job. Does it also work on large data sets? I mean it does the calculation the same way I am doing it and only later on removes the unintended values by condition. I was thinking of a more direct way to only calculate the intended correlations. But I am unsure if it plays a role with big data. Will have to test it.

Comment: edit: In addition, I need a solution which also works on data.tables or data.frames. Unfortunately, matrix calculation does not work there. Sorry for not having mentioned that in the beginning.

Comment: you can transform data.frame to matrix with as.matrix.  I don't know data.tables.

Comment: Thanks, I know this, but it can actually take a good while on larger data sets, and it is also not unproblematic, because matrices can generally only be of a single type in R.